# Pytorch: DataLoader should return only sample of one condition

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

First simple explanation what I want to achieve.

Imagine a stochastic urn model, where I would do the following. Assume, I need a batch of 256 elements

1. Pick first ball from the urn and note its color. E.g. red
2. Pick further balls from the urn.
3. If the ball is any different color, place it back in the urn
4. If the ball is red add it to the sample.
5. Repeat 3 and 4 until you have 256 red balls

Now in Torch I would like to use DataLoaders, which will return a batch of specific batch_size and its samples will be from one randomly chosen condition.

So far I have a working toy example. I can plug-in collate_fn into DataLoader as an argument. Then my batch will be a list

```
[
 [random amount of samples from condition A only ],
 [random amount of samples from condition B only ],
 [random amount of samples from condition C only ],
 ....
]
```

Unfortunately, it is not what I would like to achieve. As I wish something like

```
Batch 1:
[exactly batch_size samples from (randomly chosen) condition A]

Batch 2: 
[exactly batch_size samples from (randomly chosen) condition C]
```

Any ideas? Maybe also Torch-Native?

```
import numpy as np

b = (np.array([ 1.17, 1.65, 1.61, 7.61]), 0.0, np.array([1.]), 'file_vel_16_loc_A.wav', 206050, 'vel_16_loc_A')
c = (np.array([ 2.17, 2.65, 2.61, 2.61]), 0.0, np.array([1.]), 'file_vel_8_loc_D.wav', 206050, 'vel_8_loc_D')

batch = [b, c, b, c, b]

def collate_fn(batch):
    *_, conditions = zip(*batch)
    unique_conditions = list(set(conditions))
    condition_batches = {c: [] for c in unique_conditions}

    for b in batch:
        condition_batches[b[5]].append(b)

    batches = [list(zip(*condition_batches[c])) for c in unique_conditions]
    for i in range(len(batches)):
        for j in [0, 1, 2, 4]:
            batches[i][j] = np.stack(batches[i][j], axis=0)
    return batches


out = collate_fn(batch)


[
# here comes condition one called vel_8_loc_D
[array([[2.17, 2.65, 2.61, 2.61],
         [2.17, 2.65, 2.61, 2.61]]),
  array([0., 0.]),
  array([[1.], [1.]]),
  ('file_vel_8_loc_D.wav', 'file_vel_8_loc_D.wav'),
  array([206050, 206050]),
  ('vel_8_loc_D', 'vel_8_loc_D')],

# and now the condition two vel_16_loc_A
 [array([[1.17, 1.65, 1.61, 7.61],
         [1.17, 1.65, 1.61, 7.61],
         [1.17, 1.65, 1.61, 7.61]]),
  array([0., 0., 0.]),
  array([[1.],
         [1.],
         [1.]]),
  ('file_vel_16_loc_A.wav', 'file_vel_16_loc_A.wav', 'file_vel_16_loc_A.wav'),
  array([206050, 206050, 206050]),
  ('vel_16_loc_A', 'vel_16_loc_A', 'vel_16_loc_A')]
]
```